# How to find gravitational acceleration given $k$ in a power function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, units, data-analysis

I have a problem that has been bugging me for a week, and I can't figure it out.
We know the power function:

$$
y=kx^n
$$

I also have a set of data:

[image: Data table]

I took the natural log of both of these data to determine if a power function is a best fit:

[image]

I found the intercept to be -5.345185606

My teacher said that $k$ is e^intercept, so I found it to be 0.004771066.

Here is the question:

[image]

How do I use $k$ to find the gravity acceleration for this object?

Answer (score 1):

Let's start out by understanding what's going on when we take logaithms.

We have the relationship
$$
y=kx^n
$$
There's no obvious method for working out either $k$ or $n$ from the graph of $y$ against $x$; instead, we plot $\log(y)$ against $\log(x)$.  Why do we do that?  Well, if we take logarithms of both sides of the above equation, we get:
$$
\log(y)=\log(kx^n)=\log(k)+n\log(x)
$$
(Here, $\log$ denotes the natural log, although any other logarithm will work.)  In other words, there is a linear relationship between $\log(y)$ and $\log(x)$.  If we plot them, then the gradient will be $n$, and the $y$-intercept will be $\log(k)$.  We then know that:
$$
k=e^{y\textrm{-intercept}}
$$

In this question, we're trying to find a relationship between time and distance - so we are looking for something of the form:
$$
t=ks^n
$$
where $t$ is time and $s$ is distance.  From your $\log$-$\log$ plot, you can work out experimental values for $k$ and $n$.  According to the theory, you should get
\begin{align}
k&=g/2=9.80665/2ms^{-1}\\
n&=2
\end{align}
Do you?

Answer (score 1):

You may be surprised to learn that you have done the right thing and have got the right answer. It's just that you've used non-standard units.

Because you've put the distance in as millimetres and the time as milliseconds the value you calculate for $g/2$ is in units of millimetres per millisecond squared. You need to multiply it by a thousand to convert it to metres per second squared.